# Web3js Contract deploy never get receipt?

Tags: web3js, transactions, contract-deployment, receipts

I am trying to deploy a contract with **web3js**. The contract will be deployed but I never get to see the address, which should be returned from the promise. Instead I always get an error returned:

> Error: Failed to check for transaction receipt:

Down below my code. For debugging I introduced the event emitters `.on`:

```
contract.deploy({
    data: contractBin,
    arguments: [...]
}).send({
    from: ownerAddress,
    gas: 4000000,
    gasPrice: '30000000000000'
}).on('error', (error) => {
   console.log(`Error deploying contract ${error}`);
}).on('transactionHash', (transactionHash) => {
   console.log(`Successfully submitted contract creation. Transaction hash: ${transactionHash}`); 
}).on('receipt', (receipt) => {
   console.log(`Receipt after mining with contract address: ${receipt.contractAddress}`); 
   console.log(`Receipt after mining with events: ${JSON.stringify(receipt.events, null, 2)}`); 
}).on('confirmation', (confirmationNumber, receipt) => { 
    console.log(`Confirmation no. ${confirmationNumber} and receipt for contract deployment: `, receipt); 
}).then((instance) => {
    console.log(instance);
    let address = instance.options.address;
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Everytime I deploy a contract the transaction gets send:

> Successfully submitted contract creation. Transaction hash: 0xb87ee45a3249f2079635d987a51cad31adf5eb52f6afd987d07e84ae0d972d92

but in the next step the error of a **failed check for transaction receipt** appears. The contract gets even deployed as I can see from my geth node:

> INFO [03-09|16:51:12] Submitted contract creation              fullhash=0xb87ee45a3249f2079635d987a51cad31adf5eb52f6afd987d07e84ae0d972d92 contract=0xFEb009a6eB95bc46DEb3F35E0004D36b4b6BC6F9

And I can get the contract address from the transaction receipt:

`web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt("0xb87ee45a3249f2079635d987a51cad31adf5eb52f6afd987d07e84ae0d972d92").then(console.log);`
yields:

```
contractAddress : "0xFEb009a6eB95bc46DEb3F35E0004D36b4b6BC6F9"
```

**What am I doing wrong while deploying a contract?**

Comment: Which client are you using? ie geth, parity, ganache, etc. There's a bug agains web3js related to failing to get the receipt https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1255, you may want to check if it also applies to your situation.

Comment: I was using Geth 18.2, but since 18.3 it seems to resolved.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, this issue is [tracked on GitHub](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/2601). If you want to make web3^1.0 fire the `receipt` PromiEvent in **development** mode, you have to add the following options when constructing your web3 instance:

```js
const options = {
  transactionConfirmationBlocks: 1
};
const web3 = new Web(provider, null, options);
```